# Outputting escaped HTML with PHP includes 4 leading spaces

Tags: php, html

I'm building a form that produces basic HTML and other plain text output that users will then paste into a content management system.

I set the variables like this:

```
$date1 = $_POST['date1'];
$city1 = $_POST['city1'];
```

Then use an if-else statement to set a new variable with that will contain a chunk of the code:

```
if (!empty($date1) && empty($date2)) {
    $emaileventsectionPT = '' . $date1 . ' in ' . $city1 . '';
else (!empty($date2) && empty($date3)) { 
    $email1eventsectionPT = '' . $date1 . ' in ' . $city1 . '
    ' . $date2 . ' in ' . $city2 . '';
    }
```

Then echo that variable within the code. In this case, it's in a 
textarea all by itself on the output page:

```
<textarea id="txtfld12" onClick="SelectAll('txtfld12');" cols="75" rows="10">
    <?php 
        echo '' . $emaileventsectionPT . '';
    ?>
</textarea>
```

But that and every other textarea on the output page starts with four spaces:

```
    EVENT DATE 1 in EVENT CITY 1
EVENT DATE 2 in EVENT CITY 2
```

Which means that when I copy and paste the code (or whatever else), I have to remove those spaces every time.

I can't figure out what is causing those spaces and how to get rid of them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `textarea` code you have at least 4 newlines. This accounts for the white space you see.

Try this: render the entire block on a single line with no line breaks.

That will remove most if not all of the white space.

You will loose code readability but gain cleaner rendering of the data.

Comment: PHP newlines does not matter. 4 spaces before <?php do.

Comment: Did you try it to confirm?

Comment: Yes I am absolutely sure.

Comment: Those are HTML newlines in a textarea. In my experience they can affect layout as you describe.

Answer (score 0):

Try to write this way:

```
<textarea id="txtfld12" onClick="SelectAll('txtfld12');" cols="75" rows="10"><?php echo '' . $emaileventsectionPT . ''; ?></textarea>
```

Comment: Yes exactly.  No newlines in textarea.

Comment: @RodrigoM you absolutely do not understand the nature of the problem. Newlines are not the reason. Space between "... rows="10">" and "<?php" was the reason!